# Chrome browser remove ads?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

How can I remove the ads from the chrome browser?

[image]

Comment: did you disable all extensions?  put "chrome://extensions/" in the browser url...

Comment: turned comment into Answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put "chrome://extensions/" in the browser's url... and disable all extensions or go through them one by one until you find the culprit.